# How to get /etc/profile to run automatically in Alpine / Docker

Tags: docker, sh, ash, alpine-linux

How can I get `/etc/profile` to run automatically when starting an Alpine Docker container interactively? I have added some aliases to an `aliases.sh` file and placed it in `/etc/profile.d`, but when I start the container using `docker run -it [my_container] sh`, my aliases aren't active. I have to manually type `. /etc/profile` from the command line each time.

Is there some other configuration necessary to get `/etc/profile` to run at login? I've also had problems with using a `~/.profile` file. Any insight is appreciated!

EDIT:

Based on VonC's answer, I pulled and ran his example `ruby` container. Here is what I got:

```
$ docker run --rm --name ruby -it codeclimate/alpine-ruby:b42
/ # more /etc/profile.d/rubygems.sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bin
/ # env
no_proxy=*.local, 169.254/16
HOSTNAME=6c7e93ebc5a1
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
TERM=xterm
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
/ # exit
```

Although the `/etc/profile.d/rubygems.sh` file exists, it is not being run when I login and my `PATH` environment variable is not being updated. Am I using the wrong `docker run` command? Is something else missing? Has anyone gotten `~/.profile` or `/etc/profile.d/` files to work with Alpine on Docker? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try build Alpine Images with `ADD .profile /etc/.profile`?

Comment: No, I've never actually heard of trying to use `/etc/.profile`. I've always believed that `.profile` belongs in your `HOME` directory, whereas `profile` (no dot) belongs in `/etc`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You still can try in your Dockerfile a:

```
RUN echo '\
        . /etc/profile ; \
    ' >> /root/.profile
```

(assuming the current user is `root`. If not, replace `/root` with the full home path)

That being said, those /etc/profile.d/xx.sh should run.
See [`codeclimate/docker-alpine-ruby`](https://github.com/codeclimate/docker-alpine-ruby) as an example:

```
COPY files /
```

With '[`files/etc`](https://github.com/codeclimate/docker-alpine-ruby/tree/master/files/etc)" including an [`files/etc/profile.d/rubygems.sh`](https://github.com/codeclimate/docker-alpine-ruby/blob/master/files/etc/profile.d/rubygems.sh) running just fine.

---

In the [OP project](https://hub.docker.com/r/jkilbride/node-npm-alpine/) [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/jeff-kilbride/node-npm-alpine/blob/master/Dockerfile), there is a

```
COPY aliases.sh /etc/profile.d/
```

But the default shell is *not* a login shell (sh -l), which means [`profile` files (or those in `/etc/profile.d`) are *not* sourced](https://askubuntu.com/a/247769/5470).

Adding `sh -l` would work:

```
docker@default:~$ docker run --rm --name ruby -it codeclimate/alpine-ruby:b42 sh -l
87a58e26b744:/# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bin
```

Comment: VonC: I've tried using a `/root/.profile` file, too, with the same alias definitions I'm putting in the `/etc/profile.d/aliases.sh` file. Actually, that was the first thing I tried. I thought maybe there was something different with `ash` and `sh` on Alpine that I was missing -- some reason my `.profile` wasn't being read. I will take a look at your example. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, here's a basic `Node` container where I am using the `aliases.sh` file. Maybe someone could pull this container and see if the aliases and color prompt are working correctly when they login...  `https://hub.docker.com/r/jkilbride/node-npm-alpine/`

Comment: @JeffKilbride I have edited my answer. Maybe a chmod is missing?

Comment: VonC: Thanks for the quick update! Please see the edit I made to my original post above. I pulled and ran the `codeclimate/docker-alpine-ruby` and had the same problems. My `PATH` variable was not updated by the `rubygems.sh` file in `/etc/profile.d`.

Comment: @JeffKilbride Could you do a `ls -alrt /etc/profile.d` to see if that sh script is executable or not?

Comment: The `rubygems.sh` file is not executable, it's `rw-rw-r` or `0664`. I will give it a try on my `aliases.sh` file, but I am skeptical about that being the problem. These files are being sourced with `. filename.sh` in `/etc/profile`. They should not need to be executable. Even the example `color_prompt` file that comes with `Alpine` is not executable. And none of my files that customize the shell on other `Linux` distros are executable (e.g. `git-prompt.sh`, `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, etc...) The relevant line in `/etc/profile` is `if [ -r $script ]` -- so, it's testing for readability.

Comment: @JeffKilbride make sense, I was just checking just in case.

Comment: Have you logged into that `codeclimate/alpine-ruby` container? Does it update your `PATH` correctly? I'm wondering if this is just a problem I'm seeing or if others are having it, too. If it's more than just me, I'll post something at `alpinelinux.org`.

Comment: @JeffKilbride I am docker pulling your image as we speak.

Comment: @JeffKilbride Got it. The shell opened by default by docker run is *not* a login shell (all the details are in http://askubuntu.com/a/247769/5470). I have edited my answer, showing the right `docker run` which does work.

Comment: VonC  Awesome! I figured it was something weird with `docker`, but couldn't find an answer. The `sh -l` is working for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `sh -l` is the missing piece! Thank you for sharing this!

Answer (score 81):

The default shell in Alpine Linux is `ash`.

Ash will only read the `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` files if it is started as a login shell `sh -l`.

To force Ash to source the `/etc/profile` or any other script you want upon its invocation as a non login shell, you need to setup an environment variable called `ENV` before launching Ash.

> **Editor's note:** ENV is only sourced if the shell is interactive.

e.g. in your Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.5

ENV ENV="/root/.ashrc"

RUN echo "echo 'Hello, world!'" > "$ENV"
```

When you build that you get:

```
deployer@ubuntu-1604-amd64:~/blah$ docker build --tag test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine:3.5
3.5: Pulling from library/alpine
627beaf3eaaf: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:58e1a1bb75db1b5a24a462dd5e2915277ea06438c3f105138f97eb53149673c4
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:3.5
 ---> 4a415e366388
Step 2/3 : ENV ENV "/root/.ashrc"
 ---> Running in a9b6ff7303c2
 ---> 8d4af0b7839d
Removing intermediate container a9b6ff7303c2
Step 3/3 : RUN echo "echo 'Hello, world!'" > "$ENV"
 ---> Running in 57c2fd3353f3
 ---> 2cee6e034546
Removing intermediate container 57c2fd3353f3
Successfully built 2cee6e034546
```

Finally, when you run the newly generated container, you get:

```
deployer@ubuntu-1604-amd64:~/blah$ docker run -ti test /bin/sh
Hello, world!
/ # exit
```

Notice the Ash shell didn't run as a login shell.

So to answer your query, replace

```
ENV ENV="/root/.ashrc"
```

with:

```
ENV ENV="/etc/profile"
```

and Alpine Linux's Ash shell will automatically source the /etc/profile script each time the shell is launched.

**Gotcha:** /etc/profile is normally meant to only be sourced once! So, I would advise that you don't source it and instead source a /root/.somercfile instead.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40538356

Comment: Regarding: Editor's note: ENV is only sourced if the shell is interactive.

This https://linux.die.net/man/1/ash says: "Since the ENV file is read for every invocation of the shell, including shell scripts and non-interactive shells..." and then provides a way to restrict commands in the ENV file to interactive invocations which makes me think that ash does process ENV variable regardless of whether the shell is interactive.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by Jinesh before, the default shell in Alpine Linux is ash

```
localhost:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/ash
localhost:~$
```

Therefore simple solution is too add your aliases in .profile. In this case, I put all my aliases in ~/.ash_aliases

```
localhost:~$ cat .profile 
# ~/.profile

# Alias
if [ -f ~/.ash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.ash_aliases
fi

localhost:~$
```

.ash_aliases file

```
localhost:~$ cat .ash_aliases
alias a=alias
alias c=clear
alias f=file
alias g=grep
alias l='ls -lh'
localhost:~$
```

And it works :)

Comment: Is there an equivalent to the /etc/profile.d scan for *.sh files? I have to set some environment variables programmatically. For now I have taken Jinesh's solution, but I prefer to do it the most appropriate way possible.

Answer (score 5):

I use this:

```
docker exec -it my_container /bin/ash '-l'
```

The `-l` flag passed to ash will make it behave as a login shell, thus reading `~/.profile`