# How does ash files are structured?

Tags: linux, unix, ash

I have a small distro (not busybox) that uses ash, and I am not sure how the dot file structure is handled. .ashrc doesnt seem to be picked up nor I see a .bash_profile analog. Is there a default convention for shell startup file?

Comment: Have you considered reading the shell's man page? It's documented there, in the Invocation section.

Comment: (...it's also not really a software-development-specific question, and so not particularly on-topic on StackOverflow; Unix SE or SuperUser would be a better fit).

Answer (score 4):

This is covered in the Invocation section of the man page.

`~/.profile` is read for login shells. For non-login interactive shells to read a dotfile at startup, you need to in your environment (ie. set by `.profile`) specify the name of a file to read in `ENV`. Thus, the following will ensure that `PS1` is updated in every interactive shell created after the next login session:

```
$ echo 'export ENV=$HOME/.rc' >>"$HOME/.profile"
$ echo 'PS1="> "' >>"$HOME/.rc"
```

Comment: Hello Charles, what is the solution for non interactive non login shell(shell script), context :- I want my ansible task to pick up this environment variable

Comment: @JigarWala, I advise against that. Better to create an ansible variable (which you can do with the stdout of a shell or command module invocation, potentially one that inspects dotfile contents if that's what you really need) and set your per-task environment variables from it, as documented at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html