# Executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am working in a Dockerfile for PHP-FPM 7.1. I am ending the Dockerfile with the following line:

```
CMD ["php71-php-fpm"]
```

Because I am using `docker-compose` this is how I start up the container:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

The container compiles fine (apparently) as per this lines:

```
Successfully built 014e24455b53
WARNING: Image for service php was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating php71-fpm
```

But it ends with the following error:

```
ERROR: for php  Cannot start service php: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"php71-php-fpm\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n"
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I have tried the following:

```
CMD php71-php-fpm
```

And the error disappear but then the container exit with code 127:

```
> docker-compose ps
  Name              Command             State     Ports
-------------------------------------------------------
php71-fpm   /bin/sh -c php71-php-fpm   Exit 127
```

What I am missing here?

**UPDATE**

I have found the following answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1763178/719427):

> Value 127 is returned by /bin/sh when the given command is not found
>   within your PATH system variable and it is not a built-in shell
>   command. In other words, the system doesn't understand your command,
>   because it doesn't know where to find the binary you're trying to
>   call.

Which makes me think that the file [php71-paths.sh](https://github.com/reypm/another-lamp-docker/blob/master/php-fpm/container-files/config/init/20-php.sh) is not being executed so the paths are not setup properly.

Once again, what I am missing?

This `php71-fpm` will be linked with another container running Nginx (this is a WIP and my way to learn Docker)

Here it's the complete [Dockerfile](https://github.com/reypm/another-lamp-docker/blob/master/php-fpm/Dockerfile) for you to take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're running into trouble because the default shell run by Docker is not a login shell according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38025686/4971152), which means scripts in `/etc/profile.d/` don't get processed.

If you need profile processing, try changing your last line to `CMD ["/bin/sh", "-l", "-c", "php71-php-fpm"]` to invoke a login shell.

Comment: I got the same result as before

Comment: Are you sure that executable exists on the image? Doing `find / -name php71-php-fpm1` on your image only finds an entry in `/etc/logrotate.d`

Comment: **Note ** I did originally forget the `-c` in my answer. Sorry about that. But running the image with `CMD ["env"]` vs. `CMD ["/bin/sh", "-l", "-c", "env"]` will show the relevant php dirs in your `PATH`

Comment: This is the file [php71-paths.sh](https://github.com/reypm/another-lamp-docker/blob/master/php-fpm/container-files/config/init/20-php.sh) that should add the paths, maybe is not being executed at container start, can you take a look to the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/reypm/another-lamp-docker/blob/master/php-fpm/Dockerfile) and let me know is that's the problem and what's the solution in such case?

Comment: I do believe the container is sourcing the `php71-paths.sh` file if run with `/bin/sh -l -c ...` as evidenced by printing the environment variables in the container using `env`when it's running (`PATH` contains references to `php` directories). However my concern is that the executable named `php71-php-fpm` doesn't actually exist on your image. As stated above, I was unable to find it anywhere in the container's filesystem when it was running. Is that actually the command that needs to be run to start php? Sorry, I can't test your image at the moment.

Comment: I did found my answer [here](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/12/29/running-php-fpm-in-docker/) thanks to the great Remi (yes from RemiRepo), the solution is: `ENTRYPOINT /opt/remi/php71/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize`.  I have accepted your question because you try to help me all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this last night and solved it by using compose v2 and updating docker desktop.