# What is the bashrc equivalent in alpine linux ash?

Tags: docker, shell, alpine-linux

The title pretty much says it all (but maybe there's something more sinister in play.) I'm aware of `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` scripts that run when you *login* but that doesn't seem to work as expected when you simply start a shell. Here's an example with docker:

Create a small script :

```
$ echo "echo hello world" > startup.sh
```

Run the alpine shell with the script mounted like so:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v `pwd`/startup.sh:/etc/profile.d/statup.sh alpine sh
```

All you'll get is a shell prompt:

```
/ #
```

It does print "hello world" when you `su -` from here though:

```
/ # su -
hello world
2bf679a5677d:~#
```

But a simple `sh` to start a shell will not do:

```
/ # sh
/ #
```

So, what's the issue here? Is it an obscure Alpine Linux thing? Is it an obscure Alpine Linux Docker image thing?

Comment: Not obscure, not specific to alpine. Try running `sh yourscript.sh` or `sh -c 'echo "running"` and neither will print "hello world" (unless `yourscript.sh` contains instructions to do so).

Comment: By default, Alpine Linux uses `ash` as shell. You have therefore to define the additional file to be sourced on startup by setting `ENV`. This is explained [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ash) in the section _Invocation_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### For interactive shells

As `man ash` tells you in the **Invocation** section, the environment variable `ENV` can be used to specify a file to source during shell startup.

In your Dockerfile:

```
ENV ENV=/home/youruser/.rc
```

...and then your shell will execute the contents of `/home/youruser/.rc` during startup.

---

*In bash*, `BASH_ENV` (used when not in POSIX mode) runs even for noninteractive shells; when bash is in POSIX mode, it runs `ENV` for interactive shells only (which is the only circumstance in which the POSIX specification requires `ENV` to be honored).

Comment: *This applies even to noninteractive, non-login shells.* This is incorrect: [source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024160/how-to-get-etc-profile-to-run-automatically-in-alpine-docker#comment134164032_43743532), [source2](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html).

Comment: @ynn, read https://linux.die.net/man/1/ash (labeled as the manual for 1999 BSD ash) -- you've convinced me that ash breaks POSIX behavior, but its manual is explicit on this point. (By contrast, dash and busybox ash both honor the letter of the spec and ignore ENV in this case).

Comment: What I want to say is the documentation is incorrect in the first place. How to reproduce: (1) Write this `Dockerfile`: https://pastebin.com/drbkBQ3X (2) Execute `docker build . -t test_alpine` to build the image. (3) Execute `docker run -it --rm test_alpine` to start an interactive session. It prints `hello`, meaning `ENV` is respected. (4) Execute `docker run -it --rm test_alpine sh -c 'echo world'` to start a non-interactive session. This time, no `hello` is printed, meaning `ENV` is ignored at all.

Answer (score 6):

Dockerfile `RUN` commands and the main container `CMD` don't run any shell dotfiles, ever, on any shell, on any base Linux distribution.  This is true even if your base image includes GNU bash or you've manually reset the `SHELL` to run bash instead of standard `sh`.

The [GNU Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) probably has the best description of when dotfiles get read.  There are three cases: a shell can be a non-interactive shell; it can be an interactive shell but not a login shell; or it can be a login shell specifically.  In a Docker container, the shells you encounter usually aren't interactive shells, and if they are, they aren't login shells.

The important corollary to this is that writing shell dotfiles in Dockerfiles at all is usually incorrect.  Most paths to running commands in containers won't read them.  If you need to set an environment variable, use an `ENV` directive instead.

Some examples:

```bash
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/my_program"]
```

This *exec form* `CMD` doesn't run a shell at all.  There is no `sh` process, and nothing will ever read any shell dotfiles.

```bash
CMD my_program
# CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "my_program"]
```

This *shell form* `CMD` is automatically wrapped in `/bin/sh -c '...'`, but the shell that produces is a non-interactive shell, and doesn't read dotfiles.

```bash
docker run --rm my_image my_program
```

Again, this doesn't run a shell.

```bash
docker run --rm my_image sh -c 'my_program'
```

This explicitly supplies a shell as part of the command string, but it's not an interactive shell.

```bash
docker run --rm -it my_image sh
```

The main container command is a shell, and you haven't given it a command, and you have provided a stdin; so in this case it's an interactive shell.  If it were bash it would read `.bashrc` but not any other dotfiles.

```bash
docker run --rm -it my_image bash --login
```

The interactive shell is only a login shell if you explicitly request it.  In pretty much only this invocation, the full set of shell dotfiles will get read.

`/etc/profile.d` on its own isn't a standard shell feature.  It's a convenience provided by some distributions, but not something specifically mentioned in the bash manual.  Compare for example

```bash
docker run --rm ubuntu cat /etc/profile
docker run --rm bash cat /etc/profile
docker run --rm alpine cat /etc/profile
docker run --rm busybox cat /etc/profile
```

Notice that, in the first three cases, the `/etc/profile` files are different, but all of them contain logic to read an `/etc/profile.d` directory.  Your invocation isn't running a login shell so that file isn't getting read.

In the normal case, the thing your container is running won't be a shell.  Prebuilt images like `docker run postgres` or `docker run nginx` are typical examples: there is some specific piece of software packaged in the image, and running the container runs exactly that single piece of software.  Starting an Nginx HTTP server doesn't require a shell and doesn't read shell dotfiles.

Comment: David, thank you so much for the in depth explanation! I genuinely got smarter reading your post. After giving a second look at Charles' answer I decided to switch the "correct" checkmark over to him. I feel his answer might be more relevant to the general "bash vs alpine" title of this question as oppose to my specific use case.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming here using `alpine` linux, or specially through WSL, just add `.profile` file into the root directory.

```
apk update
apk add nano
cd ~
nano .profile
---
alias test='I work'
```

```
source ~/.profile
test
>>> I work
```

Comment: That `source` makes the answer meaningless: you could put content in a file with _any_ name and `source` would activate its contents. `.profile` is only run automatically in _login_ shells, whereas `.bashrc` is run automatically in _interactive_ shells; they have different use cases.